# iPhone simulator option aren't showing in develop option safari 13.1 and Mac OS X 10.15.4

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, ionic4, safari-web-inspector

I just update MacOS Catalina 10.15.4 and Xcode 11.3.1 now my ionic app can't have iPhone simulators in safari v 13.1 to debug. I have lot of way asked previously but can't found any solution

I also download Safari Technology Preview but also not help to much to debug my iPhone simulator

Answer (score 1):

You will need the new Safari Technology Preview for your version of MacOS. Once installed close and reopen safari. Navigate to develop -> Open Page With -> Safari Technology Preview. This will open a new instance of Safari Technology Preview and here the develop tab should show your simulator.

Comment: this worked for me! Had to install Safari Technology Preview and then load a different website in the safari in the simulator, then load back the site I intended to debug and it showed in the Safari Technology Preview browser, under develop, in the second group that is a list of devices.